# Validation not working mvc 3 properly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, validation

I am working on a project and i have some problem with my validation
Here is my model:

```
[ColumnMap("Guest_ID")]
public int Guest_ID { get; set; }

[ColumnMap("FirstName")]
[Required]
[Display(Name="FirstName")]
public  string FirstName { get; set; }

[ColumnMap("LastName")]
public string LastName { get; set; }

[ColumnMap("Phone")]
[Required]  
[MaxLength(10)]
public Nullable<int> Phone { get; set; }

[ColumnMap("AdrOras")]
[Required]
public string AdrOras { get; set; }
```

So I have required on `FirstName` and `Phone` and also `MaxLength`=10 on `Phone`.

Here is my `CreateReservation` method in my controller:

```
public ActionResult CreateReservation(int? RoomID, string FirstName, string LastName,int? Phone,string Oras,string Judet,string Tara,string Strada,int? GuestTypeId,DateTime? Birthday,DateTime? Data_Check_in, DateTime? Data_Check_out) 
{
    DBContext.Current.Open();
    Reservation rezervare = new Reservation();
    string  username= User.Identity.Name;
    Users user=Users.UserbyUsername(username);
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RoomID.ToString())&&!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName)&&!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName)&&Phone.HasValue&&!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Judet)&&!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Tara)&&!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Strada)&&!string.IsNullOrEmpty(GuestTypeId.ToString())&&Birthday.HasValue&&Data_Check_in.HasValue&& Data_Check_out.HasValue)
    {
        rezervare.CreazaRezervare(RoomID, FirstName, LastName, Phone, Oras, Judet, Tara, Strada, GuestTypeId, Birthday,user.UserID,Data_Check_in, Data_Check_out);
        return RedirectToAction("MyReservation","Reservation");
    }

    var model = GuestTyp.SelectAll();
    ReservationView rez = new ReservationView()

    {
        rezervare =rezervare,
        client = model.ToList()
    };

    DBContext.Current.Close();
    return View(rez);
}
```

And here is my view :

```
@model LicentaTest.Models.ReservationView
@using JQueryUIHelpers

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Checkout";
}

<head>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.19.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>   
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui.unobtrusive-0.5.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('input[type=text], textarea, input[type=password]').width(200);
        $('#valSum').hide();
        $('form').bind('invalid-form.validate', function (error, element) {
            $('#valSum').show("slow");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid) {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#valSum').show("slow");
        });
    </script>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateReservation", "Reservation", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <form class="form">
    <div class = "styler">
    <div id = "valSum" class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding: 0 .7em;width:500px">    
</div>
    <h6>Completare Date Rezervare</h6>
    <fieldset class="ui-widget">
        <legend class="ui-state-legend-default ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom">Date personale</legend>
            @Html.Hidden("RoomID")  
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("FirstName")
                @Html.TextBox("FirstName") 
                @Html.ValidationMessage("FirstName","Numele trebuie introdus")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("LastName    ")
                @Html.TextBox("LastName") 
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Phone")
                @Html.TextBox("Phone")  
                @Html.ValidationMessage("Phone","Numarul trebuie sa fie din maxim 10 cifre")
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Data Nasterii")
                @(Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("Birthday").MaxDate(DateTime.Now))
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.Label("Tip CLient")
                @Html.DropDownList("GuestTypeID", new SelectList(Model.client.AsEnumerable(), "GuestTypeID", "GuestType"))
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="ui-widget">
    <legend class="ui-state-legend-default ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom">Adresa</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Tara")
            @Html.TextBox("Tara")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Oras")
            @Html.TextBox("Oras")
            @Html.ValidationMessage("Oras","Field is required")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Judet")
            @Html.TextBox("Judet")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Strada")
            @Html.TextBox("Strada")
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="ui-widget">
        <legend class="ui-state-legend-default ui-corner-top ui-corner-bottom">Perioada rezervare</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Data Intrare")
            @Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("Data_Check_in")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.Label("Data Iesire")
            @Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("Data_Check_out")
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "Guest")
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
}
```

When i push create button the maxlenght validation is working but the required field validation is not working
[image]

Why is this happening what am i  doing wrong

Comment: Have you tried using the `EditorFor` instead of `TextBox`?  I've seen some strange behavior with the `TextBox` helper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 forms nested inside each other. You cannot have nested forms.

You have:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateReservation", "Reservation", FormMethod.Get)){
    <form>...</form>
}
```

Remove the `<form></form>` tags

Also...
I don't see a script tag for jQuery in your `head` section

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.19.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>   
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui.unobtrusive-0.5.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Try this...

Get jQuery and jQuery UI from CDN

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then these three need to be in this order. And ALWAYS use `@Url.Content(...)` for your scripts

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: The problem is that is only working with editorfor but its not working with textbox i need textbox because when i use editorfor i transmit null to my create rezservation method

Comment: Have you tried TextBoxFor? like so: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FieldName)`

Comment: When using textboxfor i transmit null to my method

Comment: Sounds like you have other problems beyond validation now

Comment: The problem is that the validation is working only for textboxFOR and editorFOR but is not working for textbox

Comment: What does your action look like that receives the post? You have the Get action in your question but not the Post. Update your question with that and I can see if I can help further

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create a `ViewModel` for that creation screen (Unless I'm wrong you're using more fields than the ones you have in your model, if not you can also receive the `Model` instance on the `Controller` instead of each field), so you pass a single object (instance) on the `CreateReservation` method. This will make things easier for you, and also you shall receive all the values correctly using `@Html.TextBoxFor`

Also, for checking what are you receiving on the `Controller` you can add a parameter of `FormCollection` type. With this you will be able to see each field that is being sent to the `Controller`

Edited:

After checking everything is OK according to the text above and add (if not yet) the DataAnnotations for the fields, you will be able to use  javascript validations; you can check [this](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html) post or [this one](http://www.ipreferjim.com/2011/08/dataannotations-mvc3-unobtrusive-validations/) that goes deeper

Comment: I want a javascrippt validation in my view  for all my text input but dont know how to make-it

Comment: If you do like this, and add the DataAnnotations to your ViewModel (or Model) fields you will achieve it. I edited my post to add some links that may help you